# Error when adding leaflet markercluster-src.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

On this site: http://socialarts.com/maprealdata

When I add:

```
<script src="scripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
```

I get following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Here's the L that's undefined:

```
 L.MarkerClusterGroup = L.FeatureGroup.extend({
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since it appears I have all the correct libraries? And I'm not invoking anything.

I've tried putting the `leaflet.markercluster-src.js` after the `map.js` file. Still the same error.

When I exclude the `leaflet.markercluster-src.js` there are no errors.

What I'm trying to do is simply add the markercluster libraries.

All js script tags:

```
<script type="quickload-text/javascript" src="scripts/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="quickload-text/javascript" src="scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="quickload-text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="quickload-text/javascript" src="scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="quickload-text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are adding something like `<script src="scripts/leaflet-src.js"></script>` as well, right?

Comment: ...and make sure adding leaflet before MarkerCluster

Comment: @IvanSanchez ah I thought `leaflet.js` would be enough, will test it out tonight, thanks

Comment: @sojim2 `leaflet.js` is enough - `leaflet.js` and `leaflet-src.js` have the same code, just as `leaflet.markercluster.js` and `leaflet.markercluster-src.js`. Please do update your question to include all the `<script>` tags you're using.

Comment: @IvanSanchez done and btw, the site listed above is the actual site I'm working on, if you inspect the code, you'll see the error

Comment: The culprit is very probably the `type="quickload-text/javascript"` attribute on Leaflet script tag. No clue what it is supposed to do, but it prevents the script from behaving as default. A blind attempt would be to apply the same attribute on Leaflet.markercluster script tag as well.